# OutOfMemoryException when adding large number of files in ZipFile

Tags: c#, .net, zip, dotnetzip

I am facing an issue of **OutofMemoryException** when I add **large** number of files in **ZipFile**. The sample code is as below:

```
ZipFile file = new ZipFile("E:\\test1.zip");
file.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.AsNecessary;
file.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1;
for (Int64 i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
   file.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.None;
   byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("rama");
   ZipEntry entry = file.AddEntry(@"myFolder1/test1/myhtml111.html" + i.ToString(), data);
}
file.Save();
```

I have downloaded the source Code of **Ionic.zip** library and I see that for every Add*() function like AddEntry(), AddFile() etc. they add item into Dictionary called **_entry**.

This dictionary **does not** get cleared when we call **Save()** or **Dispose()** methods on **ZipFile** object.

I feel this is the root cause of OutOfMemoryException.

How do I overcome this issue? Is there any other way to achieve the same result without running into OutOfMemoryException? Am I missing something?
I am open to using other open Source libraries too.

Comment: Sounds like you are running out of memory. Are you compiling to 32-bit? If so, try to compile it to 64-bit. 32-bit applications has a memory limit of 2gb

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary holding the internal structure of the archvie shouldn't be a problem. 
Assuming your entry 'path' is a string of about **50** bytes - even 1000000 entries should amount to about **50 Mb** (a lot - but nowhere near the limit of 2 Gb) - while I haven't bothered checking the size of the ZipEntry - I also doubt it would be large enough (would need to be around 2kb each)

I also think that your expectation for this Entry dictionary to be cleared is wrong. Since this is the informational structure of the contents of the zip file - you need it to hold all the entries.

***From this point on I am going to assume that the posted code:***

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("rama");
```

***Is a place holder for actual file data in bytes (since for 1M x 4 bytes - should be under 4Mb)***

The most likely issue here that the declared byte[] data remains in memory  untill the entire ZipFile is disposed.
It makes sense to keep this array untill the data is saved.
The simplest way to work around this is to wrap the ZipFile in using re-opening and closing for every file you want to add.

```
        var zipFileName = "E:\\test1.zip";
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        {
            using (ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(zipFileName))
            {

                byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(file2Zip);

                ZipEntry entry = zf.AddEntry(@"myFolder1/test1/myhtml111.html" + i.ToString(), data);

                zf.Save();
            }

        }
```

This approach might seem wasteful if you are saving a lot of small files, since you are using byte[] directly it would be quite simple to implement a buffering mechanism.

While it is true that it's possible to side step this issue by compiling to 64-bit, unless you are really just barelly going over the 2Gb limit, this would create a **very memory hungry app.**

Comment: Thanks for reply. **Byte[]** was not an issue as I have tried setting it to **null** and that made no difference. The dictionary in question holds **ZipEntry** objects. These objects are never released as dictionary keeps reference to them. I tested this application with some profilers and **ZipEntry** objects and Dictionary were shown as offenders. Calling Save() or Dispose() on **ZipFile** object does not release the memory as I would have expected.

Comment: @Himanshu1983 setting the data to null doesn't do anything - the framework handles loop scoping correctly. IT is the *ZipEntry/ZipFile* objects which keeps the byte arrays alive internally (possibly as memory stream) - which makes sense since untill they are saved they do not exist in the file. AS far as the dictionary is concerned there is no getting around its existance.